# Does django have some inbuilt model getter functionality? I've "lost" a function

Tags: django, model

I'm just.. I dunno.

The model is calling `self.get_next_by_context_start()`. And it *works*. I can call it in a shell.

But I've grepped the entire codebase and... it's just... not there.

`grep -r "get_next_by_context_start"` - this lists just two instances of the string, both times where the function is being *called*. There's no `def get_next_by_context_start` *anywhere*.

How am I being this stupid? How can I lose an entire function?

Comment: This is [a Django "magic" feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO)

Answer (score 0):

GAAAHHHH.

[get_next_by_FOO()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) is an inbuilt Django model function.

Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry. I didn't know this. It looks useful.